# Is it Exponential Decay?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I am reviewing algebra 2 and stuck with this question.

The population P of a city is given by

```
p =  25000e^kt
```

where t is the time in years, with t = 0 corresponding
to the year 1990. In 1945, the population was 3,350. Find the value of k.

The solution proposed by my prof looks like this:

```
3350 = 25000e^k(-45)
```

My question is why is there a negative sign in front of `45`.

Is that because the population is decreasing (i.e. exponential decay)?

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is useful for removing ambiguities in expressions such as e^kt and e^k(-45), like this: $$p = 25000 e^{kt}$$ Then, substituting $t=-45 = 1945-1990$ and $p=3350$, $$3350 = 25000 e^{k (-45)}$$

Comment: Since 1945 is prior to 1990, $t$ must be negative. The population is not necessarily decreasing.

Comment: That's right, $t = 1945-1990=-45$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Year $t=0$ is $1990$. The other year you know about ($1945$) is in the past. Looking backwards in time looks like decay. If you solve the equation you've written you will get a positive $k$. It's $t$ that's negative.

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you pls elaborate a little more?

Comment: The `-` sign is used because the population is decreasing right?

Comment: The population _is_ increasing over time. It was a lot larger in $1990$ than it was in $1945$. If you look from any time into the past you will find a smaller population. Just go ahead and solve your equation for $k$, which will turn out positive. Then plug in $t=0$ and $t=-45$ and check that you get what you should.

Comment: No, the $-$ sign is used because because if the clocks are set with the year $1990$ corresponding to time $t=0$ then the year $1945$ corresponds to $t=1945-1990=-45$.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.